# How can I detect video url and download video from url which isn’t end with “.mp4”?

Tags: ios, swift, video, webkit, nsurl

I need to detect video which is in the url. I know how can I download videos directly from video url. However, I need to download videos indirect urls. For example, I clicked any youtube video link and then I want to detect direct video url and download it from direct video url on this page. 
In other words, how can I find ".mp4" extension link on the web page? Here is the code which I use, but it is only work if url ends with ".mp4"

```
@IBAction func downloadButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let urlString = "https://example.com/sample.mp4"
    downloadVideoLinkAndCreateAsset(urlString)

}



func downloadVideoLinkAndCreateAsset(_ videoLink: String) {

    // use guard to make sure you have a valid url
    guard let videoURL = URL(string: videoLink) else { return }

    guard let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }

    // check if the file already exist at the destination folder if you don't want to download it twice
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(videoURL.lastPathComponent).path) {

        // set up your download task
        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: videoURL) { (location, response, error) -> Void in

            // use guard to unwrap your optional url
            guard let location = location else { return }

            // create a deatination url with the server response suggested file name
            let destinationURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(response?.suggestedFilename ?? videoURL.lastPathComponent)

            do {

                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)

                PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (authorizationStatus: PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in

                    // check if user authorized access photos for your app
                    if authorizationStatus == .authorized {
                        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: destinationURL)}) { completed, error in
                                if completed {
                                    print("Video asset created")
                                } else {
                                    print(error as Any)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                })

            } catch { print(error) }

            }.resume()

    } else {
        print("File already exists at destination url")
    }

}
```

Comment: In other words, `how can I find ".mp4" extension link` on the web page? Here is the code which I use, `but it is only work if url ends with ".mp4"` -- so what is a problem?

Comment: I want to detect videos if the url is not end with “.mp4” extension. Is this clean now?

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko In other words, How can I extract mp4 file from the url which is not ends with “.mp4” ?

Comment: if it is not ended with .mp4, then it means that it is not a .mp4 file. It could be a reference to .mp4 or something like that. You need to parse it and find exactly link that is ended with .mp4

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko Let me explain with an example. “https://youtu.be/_hyAOYMUVDs” this is a youtube video link but this url is not ending with .mp4. However there is a video on this link. How can I find and extract this video’s mp4 url with code?

Comment: This link is leading not to .mp4 file but to web-page that contain .mp4 file. You need to parse DOM structure of this web page and look up for link with .mp4. But exactly for this page it seems to be impossible, because YouTube hide it, so you can access to youtube video only thru their API's

Comment: There's no guarantee that a url should contains a file extension.  `https://sub.domain.com/video` could be a video file. Even if `https://sub.domain.com/video.jpg` could be a video file too. It depends on the path structure of the web service.